# Maven: downloading an old snapshot from Nexus snapshot repo instead of latest

Tags: maven, mule

I am using "mvn dependency:copy" command to download the latest SNAPSHOT jars or release jar from Nexus depending if it's a SNAPSHOT version or a release version from the pom.xml.

Command below for reference. However, when I try to download the snapshot version, I observe that maven downloads an older version of jar instead of picking the latest snapshot version.

```html
mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=${GROUP_ID}:${ARTIFACT_ID}:${VERSION}:jar:${PACKAGING} \
-DdistributionManagement.releaseRepository.repoId=${NEXUS_RELEASE_REPO_ID} \
-DdistributionManagement.snapshotRepository.repoId=${NEXUS_SNAPSHOT_REPO_ID} \
-DdistributionManagement.repository.releaseURL=${NEXUS_RELEASE_URL} \
-DdistributionManagement.repository.snapshotURL=${NEXUS_SNAPSHOT_URL} -DoutputDirectory=.
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details. What are the files names, how dou know which one is older. What is the relationship with the mule tag?

Comment: Supplemental question: Why do you use mvn dependency:copy? What kind of problem are you trying to solve? Please explain much more details...

Comment: Have you tried the command with the additional flag `-U`?

Comment: @aled I am using mule maven plugin for the mule application. Attached the image for reference

Comment: @khmarbaise I am trying to download the jar from nexus and promote it to a higher environment as part of the release process as I don't intend to do a fresh build.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I can try with -U flag. I am using maven 3.3 version. Not sure if it's the issue with Maven version. Do I need to clean up old snapshots. Have attached the image for clarity.

Comment: If you promote artifacts you should do that only with releases and never with SNAPSHOT's...

Comment: @khmarbaise This is for the QA environment. Don't want to call it a release as there might be defects anticipated out of QA. Hence SNAPSHOT.

Comment: It leaves development so it's a release...otherwise how could associate issues related to the version in QA to the correct code state and fix issue... A release is more correct and even easier to handle...

Comment: @JFabianMeier I tried with -U flag, it worked fine. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may need to use the `-U` or `--update-snapshots` option to force a check for updated snapshots on remote repositories.

The default is that it will only update snapshots once a day. That is when the first build of the day is executed.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thanks!